# how can I use sed to delete second line?

Tags: arrays, bash, sed

I have a text file 3.txt, content like this

```
123.ooo
aaaa - bbbb ccccc, dddd dddd, eeee fff (hhhhh ii jjj) 890a fff rrr 98.jjjj.1234
444.kkk
```

read 3.txt into array VAR

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=$(cat /tmp/3.txt)
LEN=${#VAR[@]}
for (( i=0; i<${LEN}; i++ ));
do
  echo ${VAR[$i]}
  sed -i -e "#"${VAR[$i]}"#d" /tmp/3.txt
  cat /tmp/3.txt
done
```

I want to `echo 123.ooo` then delete the `123.ooo` line in `/tmp/3.txt`
then `echo aaaa - bbbb ccccc, dddd dddd, eeee fff (hhhhh ii jjj) 890a fff rrr 98.jjjj.1234` and delete this line in `/tmp/3.txt`
but second line have space, how can I use sed to delete second line?

Sorry about my poor English.
I want to `echo` first line, then delete first line in file.
`echo` second line, then delete second line in file.
`echo` third line, then delete third line in file.

Comment: What is your actual requirement? delete lines containing patterns `123.ooo` and `aaaa - bbbb ccccc, dddd dddd, eeee fff (hhhhh ii jjj) 890a fff rrr 98.jjjj.1234` in the file? Your script seems pretty roundabout for a such a trivial task. Just do `sed -i.bak -e '/123.ooo/d' -e '/aaaa - bbbb ccccc, dddd dddd, eeee fff (hhhhh ii jjj) 890a fff rrr 98.jjjj.1234/d' file` and be done with it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a representative example of your input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: sorry about my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking this as an exercise in using arrays and `sed`:

The issue with your code is that file is read as a single value into the variable `VAR` whereas you want to create an array with each line as its own array entry.

To assign to an array use

```
VAR=( ... )
```

To split the input on newlines, set the `IFS` variable to the value of a single newline.

You also have another issue with you `sed` editing script. You seem to want to use `#` as the delimiter for the regular expression (which is actually a "`sed` address").  If you want to do this, the first `#` has to be escaped (`\#`). It is only the arguments to the `s` and `y` `sed` editing commands that takes any unescaped character as delimiters.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
VAR=( $(cat /tmp/3.txt) )
LEN=${#VAR[@]}
for (( i=0; i<${LEN}; i++ ));
do
  echo ${VAR[$i]}
  sed -i -e "\#"${VAR[$i]}"#d" /tmp/3.txt
  cat /tmp/3.txt
done
```

Or, with a bit of cleanup:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

VAR=( $(</tmp/3.txt) )
LEN=${#VAR[@]}

for (( i = 0; i < LEN; i++ )); do
    echo ${VAR[$i]}
    sed -i -e "\#${VAR[$i]}#d" /tmp/3.txt
    cat /tmp/3.txt
done
```